# Select every row from every table in database where (columnName = value) if column name exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and am logged in as `sa`. I would like to query every table in my database for whether it has a certain column name. And if so append every row where (columnNameValue = someValue) to a results table. Then return said results table.

There are a few similar problems with solutions out there. Notably I can use `sp_MSForeachTable` for this but it lacks any kind of documentation. I can use `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to get a list of all the tables.

The following solution ([link text](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm)) will go every table & every column to find a certain value in the cell. Which is different from finding a certain value in the cell IF that column is a certain columnName.

Writing a nested while statement should be possible but are there any inbuilt commands to run queries like this?

Pseudo-Code if it helps :

```
foreach(table in tableList) {
    if (table.hasColumnName(SOME_COLUMN) {
       EXEC ('SELECT * FROM table WHERE (SOME_COLUMN = SOME_VALUE)')
    }
}
```

[Edit]

Rather then having a single results set I would like to be a single result per table as long as the select returns at least one row. This should give a very large amount of different results as expecting a join or union to work is unrealistic.

If possible I would like to append the tablename to start of each result.

I have a simple query below that gets all the results but It will display empty tables and doesnt give any visual indication in individual results as to what table it belongs to:

[Further Edit]

Updated the query below to include the IF EXIST check that removes NULL results & the select name AS source column to add the table source to the results thanks to @Martin

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_VALUE nvarchar(512), @VALUE nvarchar(10);

SET @COLUMN_VALUE = 'id'
SET @VALUE = '0';

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(512), @COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(512), @QUERY nvarchar(512);

SET @TABLE_NAME = '';

WHILE @TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @TABLE_NAME =
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TABLE_NAME
    );
    PRINT 'Table name : ' + @TABLE_NAME;
    SET @COLUMN_NAME = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE (TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TABLE_NAME, 1))
            AND (COLUMN_NAME = @COLUMN_VALUE)

    );
    PRINT 'Column name : ' + @COLUMN_NAME;
    IF @COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY = 
            'SELECT ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''' AS Source, * ' +
            'FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' ' +
            'WHERE (' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + @VALUE + ')'
        EXEC
        (
            'IF EXISTS(' + @QUERY + ') ' + @QUERY
        )
    END     
END
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if TableA has two columns and TableB has three?

Comment: @Lieven There is no need for all the results to be merged into one table as its horribly unreadable so returning a single results set for each table that has said columnName is valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
SOME_COLUMN VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE bar
(
SOME_COLUMN VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO bar VALUES ('SOME_VALUE')


DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)

SELECT 
      @Query = isnull(@Query + ';','') + 
      'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + 
      QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' WHERE SOME_COLUMN=''SOME_VALUE'')
      SELECT ''' + o.name +''' AS Source, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + 
      QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' WHERE SOME_COLUMN=''SOME_VALUE'''
FROM sys.columns c 
JOIN sys.objects o
ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE o.type IN ('U','V') AND c.name = 'SOME_COLUMN'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Could you clarify what `schema_id` and `object_id` should be? I realised that asking for th results set to be a large JOIN with a lot of columns is useless.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? These are columns in `sys.tables`

Comment: It throws the http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/all_queries_must_have_an_equal_number_of_expressions_p1.aspx error for me. I forget to mention theres no garantuee that all the tables will have said column name in them.

Comment: @Martin, I believe it's better to replace the UNION ALL with GO;. The UNION would only work if all tables have the same column definitions (wich apparently they don't). How it get's inserted into another table after that is going to be tricky to say the least.

Comment: @Raynos - That's what the filter on `c.name` is for. Your problem is that not all of the tables *with* the column are UNION compatible - This is obviously a requirement for your proposal to work. Can you replace `*` with a specific column list that all tables with the column will have? If not will @Lieven's suggestion work for you? (To bring back the result sets individually)

Comment: Bringing back the results set individually is a better option. There is no need to insert it into a new a table. Returning multiple results would be fine.

Comment: @Raynos In that case just ditch the `UNION ALL ` and replace it with a semi colon ';'

Comment: In that case that does exactly what I need it to do. Except it shows a lot of empty result windows. Is it possible to filter those out? Your query returns less results then my manual WHILE loop. I cant identify why that is.

Comment: That works fine. But compared to my manual query it still returns less results. I cant identify why some tables are ignored. Can you explain the query. I cant see how foo & bar magically make it work.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are just demo tables. Sorry no idea why you would get different results. You'll have to figure that one out yourself.

Comment: @Martin Thank you. I didnt notice foo & bar were examplar data. I've updated my manual query which returns the same as you but returns more results set. I dont really understand your higher level code too well. Can you see anything that is semanticly different?

Comment: @Raynos `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` returns Views as well as base tables maybe that is the reason?

Comment: @Martin thats exactly what it is. Is it easy to edit your query to include views?